# What is the easiest way to check if time is set in datetime variable

Tags: php

I have function one of the arguments of which is `$date` variable.

Sometimes there is time in the date (like `2018-01-01 15:40:43`),

sometimes - there is not (like `2018-01-01`).

I want to know if time is set.
What is the easiest way to do it?

Here is what I tryied:

```
function checkDate ($date) {
   $time = date("H:i:s", strtotime($date));
   if ($time == '00:00:00') {
       //time was not set!
   }
}
```

Obviously, this works, but untill something like `2018-06-01 00:00:00` is passed.

I would not like using `explode` of string if there is some other solution.

Thank you/.

Comment: So the "date" you are evaluating is a string? You know the data best. Could you just check for `:` or string length?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use date_parse

check this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php

[image]

you can check for the minutes, hours and seconds from the resulting array :D

also you can check for errors in date.

[image]

Comment: Looks like most elegant solution `if (isset(date_parse($date))['hour']) { // time was set!}`

Comment: for what you need, you need to use !empty instead of isset, because the variable is already set :), so you can use if(!empty(date_parse($date)['hour']))...

Comment: You need to use `!== false` because hour can be set but 0

`if (date_parse($date)['hour'] !== false) { // time was set!}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Datetime class to test.  What the code below will do is attempt to create a Datetime object from a date as long as it is in the format that is specified.

So if you pass anything other than a date that is in the time format that you specify it will error.  Then you use the getLastErrors() to check.

Like so:

```
function checkIsDate($date){

  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
  $date_errors = DateTime::getLastErrors();

  if ($date_errors['warning_count'] + $date_errors['error_count'] == 0) {

  return TRUE;

  } else {

    return FALSE;

    }

}

echo checkIsDate('2018-05-29')?'True':'False'; //<-- Will return true;
echo checkIsDate('2018-05-29 11:30:00')?'True':'False'; //<-- Will return false;
echo checkIsDate('05/29/2018')?'True':'False'; //<-- Will return false;
```

Comment: Nice approach indeed. I'm tempted to remove my answer :)

Comment: Maybe embellish the answer with some example input/output. Date, date and time, other. Very nice.

Comment: Thank you guys, and explained a little better.

Comment: Side note: `$date_errors['warning_count'] + $date_errors['error_count'] == 0` is already a boolean expression that can be returned as-is.

Comment: @Álvaro González Did not know that, thank you.  I edited my answer.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's a plain string functions version:

```
$input = [
    '2018-01-01',
    '2018-01-01 15:40:43',
    '2018-01-01 00:00:00',
];
foreach ($input as $string) {
    list($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minutes, $seconds) = array_pad(preg_split('/[^\\d]+/i', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY), 6, null);
    printf("%s has time? %s\n", $string, $hour!==null ? 'Yes' : 'No');
}
```

```
2018-01-01 has time? No
2018-01-01 15:40:43 has time? Yes
2018-01-01 00:00:00 has time? Yes
```

Tweak checks to your liking.

I would not recommend this though. Native date/time functions are way better coping with invalid input.